# Adding a delay or Pause before starting the effects on the first element in Jquery

Tags: jquery, delay

HTML:

```
  <div id="main-trannies" class="fivecol last">
  <h2>What I am is:</h2>
  <ul class="js_transitions">
    <li>awesome</li>
    <li>egotistical/li>
    <li>not conceited</li>
    <li class="final"><h3>Da Best</h3></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS using Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js_transitions li").each(function(i) {
$(this).hide().fadeIn(i*5000);
  });
});
```

I know there is a delay, but where do you put .delay when you just want to pause the first element in an array until like, 10 seconds (100000) after ready, or page load.  I want these li elements to just fadeIn after 10 seconds like how credits in a movie kind of come in... that was the original idea, but i'll take them just appearing and sticking.

Lasly, I know some guys use `display:none` for hiding in css, but i want to make sure non-js browser at least display something.

My jquery fu is weak, at best... so let me know if i'm doing anything wrong thus far.  Unlike most of you, i don't have a frail geekgo (ego).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `delay`

```
$(function(){
 $(".js_transitions li").hide();
 $(".js_transitions li").delay(10000).each(function(i) {
 $(this).fadeIn(i*5000);
  });
});
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/T5QsA/10/

Comment: thanks @3nigma and for the fiddle.  I'll need to work on the css, as there is a 'jump' down when the div tag loads all these li's after the delay.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

setTimeout(functionTodoAfter10Seconds,(10000));

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $(".js_transitions li").hide(); // hide at DOM ready
  setTimeout(function(){
     $(".js_transitions li").each(function(i) {
     $(this).fadeIn(i*5000);
       });
     },(10000));
});
```

working demo http://jsfiddle.net/T5QsA/9/

Answer (score 0):

Easy! This one delays 420ms before running the function.

```
$(document).ready().oneTime("420ms",function(){$("div#main").show();
});
```

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers